# sum of two wishart matrices

Tags: probability, matrices

Assuming $\mathbf{H}_1\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times M}(M>K),\mathbf{H}_2\in\mathbb{C}^{K\times M} $, the entries of $\mathbf{H}_1\text{ and }\mathbf{H}_2$ are all i.i.d. $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$.
I know that $\mathbf{W}_1=\mathbf{H}_1\mathbf{H}_1^H\sim \mathcal{W}_K(M,\mathbf{I})$,  $\mathbf{W}_2=\mathbf{H}_2\mathbf{H}_2^H\sim \mathcal{W}_K(M,\mathbf{I})$, and $\mathbf{W}_1+\mathbf{W}_2\sim \mathcal{W}_K(2M,\mathbf{I})$. 
Is $\mathbf{W}=\alpha\mathbf{W}_1+\beta\mathbf{W}_2$ ($\alpha,\beta$ are pre-fixed integer) also a wishart distribution? If so, $\mathbf{W}\sim\mathcal{W}_?(?,?)$.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha\ne \beta$, then $\alpha \mathbf{W}_1 + \beta \mathbf{W}_2$ is not distributed according to any standard standard distribution. Even with $M=K=1$, $\mathbf{W}_1+\mathbf{W}_2\sim \chi^2(2)$, but $\mathbf{W}_1 + 2\mathbf{W}_2\sim X_1^2 + 2 X_2^2$ where $X_1,X_2$ are i.i.d. standard normal. But that latter variable has no well-known distribution, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The resultant distribution involves a hypergeometric function of matrix argument. Please have a look at this http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6638

Interestingly, the eigenvalue statistics of such weighted sum of Wisharts (any number) can be exactly evaluated. http://arXiv.org/abs/1504.00222